# Accessing XML File Over Network

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

I have been working on this management application for weeks now and it's almost finished. What is supposed to happen when a user clicks the save button, a VerifyFields() method is called. After that it is supposed to ask the user if they want to save and send an email. Once the user clicks Yes it is supposed to send an email to the email addresses in an XML file. I am getting the error message "The file:DREmailAddresses.xml was not found at:\fs01\Applications\EMS-Manager." However, the file is there and is accessible. I've copied the relevant code below as well as an [image of the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPijM.png).

```
// Begin Email Section
    public bool VerifyFields()
    {
        var status = false;
        switch (tbxDynPartNumber.Text)
        {
            case "":
                MessageBox.Show(@"Enter Dynalab Part#", @"Input Needed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                status = true;
                break;
        }
        switch (tbxSupplier.Text)
        {
            case "":
                MessageBox.Show(@"Enter Supplier Name", @"Input Needed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                status = true;
                break;
        }
        switch (tbxInitiatedBy.Text)
        {
            case "":
                MessageBox.Show(@"Enter Initiator Name", @"Input Needed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                status = true;
                break;
        }
        switch (orderQty.Text)
        {
            case "0":
                MessageBox.Show(@"Order Quantity Must Be Greater Than 0!", @"Input Needed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                status = true;
                break;
        }

        switch (dtpDate.Text)
        {
            case "":
                MessageBox.Show(@"Enter A Valid Date.", @"Input Needed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                status = true;
                break;
        }
        switch (tbxDescription.Text)
        {
            case "":
                MessageBox.Show(@"Enter Description", @"Input Needed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                status = true;
                break;
        }

        switch (tbxLocation.Text)
        {
            case "":
                MessageBox.Show(@"Enter Location", @"Input Needed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                status = true;
                break;
        }
        switch (tbxDiscrepancyDescription.Text)
        {
            case "":
                MessageBox.Show(@"Enter Discrepancy Description", @"Input Needed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                status = true;
                break;
        }
        return status;
    }

    public void PrepareEmail(string subject, string message)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show(@"Are you sure you want to save and send Discrepancy Report: " +tbxDRNumber.Text + @"?\n Click YES to save\n Click NO to cancel" , @"Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {

            SendEmail(subject,message);
        }
    }
    public Array AddEmail()
    {
        string[] dRemail = { "", "", "" };
        if (File.Exists(@"\\fs01\Applications\EMS-Manager\DREmailAddresses.xml"))
        {
            XmlReader emailDocument = new XmlTextReader(@"\\fs01\Applications\EMS-Manager\DREmailAddresses.xml");
            while (emailDocument.Read())
            {
                var type = emailDocument.NodeType;
                switch (type)
                {
                    case XmlNodeType.Element:
                        if (emailDocument.Name == "DRCreatedAddEmail")
                        {
                            dRemail[0] = emailDocument.ReadInnerXml();
                        }
                        if (emailDocument.Name == "DRActionNeededAddEmail")
                        {
                            dRemail[1] = emailDocument.ReadInnerXml();
                        }
                        if (emailDocument.Name == "DRPendingAddEmail")
                        {
                            dRemail[2] = emailDocument.ReadInnerXml();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(
                                @"The file: 'DREmailAddresses.xml' was not found at: \\fs01\Applications\EMS-Manager");
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        return dRemail;
    }
```

Comment: Not an answer but the [docs for XmlTextReader say](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1af7xa52(v=vs.110).aspx) say _"Starting with the .NET Framework 2.0, we recommend that you create XmlReader instances by using the XmlReader.Create method to take advantage of new functionality."_

Comment: Looking at the code you don't seem to understand switch statements. All of these could have been done with simple if statement s.

Comment: You are correct about if statements. It may be useful to modify the code to use if statements in place of the switch statements. Also I am very new to programming and still learning. I have taught myself everything and I make mistakes, it's all part of learning. However we are going over Switch statements next week in class. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting that error message, then your code is getting past the check for File.Exists and past the Reading of the document, but just hitting the else branch of the "if (emailDocument.Name == "DRPendingAddemail")" check.

So your function should be something close to this

```
public Array AddEmail()
{
    string[] dRemail = { "", "", "" };
    if (File.Exists(@"\\fs01\Applications\EMS-Manager\DREmailAddresses.xml"))
    {
        XmlReader emailDocument = new XmlTextReader(@"\\fs01\Applications\EMS-Manager\DREmailAddresses.xml");
        while (emailDocument.Read())
        {
            var type = emailDocument.NodeType;
            switch (type)
            {
                case XmlNodeType.Element:
                    if (emailDocument.Name == "DRCreatedAddEmail")
                    {
                        dRemail[0] = emailDocument.ReadInnerXml();
                    }
                    else if (emailDocument.Name == "DRActionNeededAddEmail")
                    {
                        dRemail[1] = emailDocument.ReadInnerXml();
                    }
                    else if (emailDocument.Name == "DRPendingAddEmail")
                    {
                        dRemail[2] = emailDocument.ReadInnerXml();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Unknown node type " + emailDocument.Name);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
         MessageBox.Show(@"The file: 'DREmailAddresses.xml' was not found at: \\fs01\Applications\EMS-Manager");
    }
    return dRemail;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I will try you suggestion. I didn't even realize that it was checking all those conditions. Also, since I am new to SO, how do I accept an answer?

Comment: I have converted from switch statements to if statements and I am getting the same results.

Comment: Make sure you have the else statement exactly where I put it in my example. If you know how to use the debugger in visual studio, put a breakpoint in both else statements and see which one is executed. One thing to note, is that I added a new code path where your old MessageBox used to be with a different error message, so make sure that you are seeing the correct message ("file nout found" vs. "unknown node type")

Comment: Ok, your solution did help and I now see why you created the unknown node type message box. I am now receiving the message: "Unknown node type Data." Obviously the first portion is the string "Unknown node type" and the second is the emailDocument.Name. So, looking through the XML file which I did not create I found <Data> </Data> I am guessing it is using the <Data> as a node type and it is unknown.

Comment: Can you send a copy of your XML file over? Just as an FYI, the way the XMLReader works, if you had a document like the following (http://pastebin.com/YVX38ezw), the way XML Reader works, in the first run of the while(emailDocument.read()) loop, it would be looking at the A element, next loop would be B, and the next would be D, followed by C then E.

Comment: I just realized that my resolution was identical to yours. So I had to delete my answer(s) to assure you were given the correct credit for this. Thank you for your help. Also you are correct the code was just stopping after the first loop through the XML file. I did edit my code as suggested by you and it worked. So, thanks again.